# ST_AsLatLonText and precision

Tags: geolocation, postgis

I though I could repeat the DMS tokens for the desired precision:

ST_AsLatLonText(ST_MakePoint(center_lon1, center_lat1), 'DDDMMMSSS')

But that is resulting in values like:

2759N
422351E

So the precision does not seem to be padding?  I would think it should be
02705900
and
042023051

Is there anyway to get the ST_AsLatLonText to pad in the 0s?

Answer (score 0):

it's perhaps a bit dirty, but one could "fix" the padding a posteriori:

```
SELECT
  regexp_replace(
    regexp_replace(
      ST_AsLatLonText(ST_MakePoint(42.3975, 27.9833), 'DDDMMMSSSC')
      , ' ', '0', 'g'
    ),
    '([NS])0', '\1 ');
```

which yields

```
    regexp_replace     
-----------------------
 027058060N 042023051E
(1 row)
```